# Extending Optimum WiFi range

Tags: wireless, bridge

How would one go about extending an optimum wifi connection? I would assume a bridge would be better than a repeater so the network wouldn't suffer from reduced bandwidth, however I have learned I would need to know the MAC address of their router which I do not have access to... what would you suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions from an end-user of a corporate network are specifically off-topic. You will need to ask this of the network administrators.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Questions by end users of a network not within their control or of a service provider network are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You run a cable to the network and add an access point; you did say optimum, and optimum is carried on wires (and fibers) until it reaches an AP which is physically near the end user devices.